# How can I connect to Cloudant from a Flask App running in Bluemix?

Tags: python, flask, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I have seen a flask sample project for Bluemix: https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/bluemix-python-flask-sample

How can I connect to Cloudant from this flask application?

**Note:**

- I know how to use flask.
- I have seen the instructions for connecting to Cloudant using the [requests](https://cloudant.com/blog/using-python-with-cloudant/#.VW1fHudnlK4) library and that is the approach I would like to use.
- I have seen the Cloudant [API documentation](https://docs.cloudant.com/api.html) and I am comfortable with the different API methods.

Comment: downvoters: please say why you are down voting so that the question can be improved.  no comments = no clue what is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The steps I followed to make the [flask sample project](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/bluemix-python-flask-sample)  work:

1. Follow the instructions in the sample project README and deploy your code to Bluemix
2. Login to the Bluemix console and add a Cloudant service to your application
3. Modify the `welcome.py` and `requirements.txt` source code to connect to Cloudant.  (see example below)
4. Use `cf push` to push your changes to Cloudant.
5. Hit the url `http://yourbluemixurl/createdb/test` to create a database named 'test'

Example code:

**welcome.py**

```
import os
import json
import requests
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.update(
    DEBUG=True,
)

@app.route('/')
def welcome():
    return 'Welcome to flask and Cloudant on Bluemix.'

@app.route('/createdb/<db>')
def create_db(db):
    try:
        vcap = json.loads(os.getenv("VCAP_SERVICES"))['cloudantNoSQLDB']

        cl_username = vcap[0]['credentials']['username']
        cl_password = vcap[0]['credentials']['password']

        url         = vcap[0]['credentials']['url']
        auth        = ( cl_username, cl_password )

    except:
        return 'A Cloudant service is not bound to the application.  Please bind a Cloudant service and try again.'

    requests.put( url + '/' + db, auth=auth )
    return 'Database %s created.' % db

port = os.getenv('VCAP_APP_PORT', '5000')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=int(port))
```

**requirements.txt**

```
Flask==0.10.1
requests==2.7.0
```